# How to remove a fragment of a shape in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a circle and I want to remove a fragment. I tried to use a square to include the fragment.
[image]

But none of the `Merge Shapes` could achieve it.

So how to do it properly?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Pie shape tool

[image: Pie Shape Tool]

Draw a Pie just as you would a circle (hold down shift to make it same width and height). Grab the yellow marker to adjust the size of the segment that is removed from the complete circle.

[image: Drawing a Pie]

Change the fill and line colour as for any other shape, then choose "Edit Points" from the right-mouse context menu.

[image: Choose Edit Points]

Select one of the straight segments and choose "Delete Segment" from the right-mouse context menu.

[image: Delete a straight segment]

If the other "straight" segment now changes into a curved line (it does on my version of PowerPoint), right-click and change it into a "Straight Segment" before proceeding.

[image: Correct segment into Straight segment]

Now at this point, I don't understand why PowerPoint doesn't allow you to delete the other straight segment, but so long as it is a straight segment, you can just move the point in the centre of the circle to be exactly on top of the point at the other end of the straight segment to essentially remove that segment. It may be that newer versions of PowerPoint don't have this quirk.

[image: A circle with a segment missing]

Finally click anywhere outside the shape to exit from "Edit points" mode.

Comment: Wonderful! The next segment can be deleted by "delete point"

Comment: Glad that worked for you. My version of PowerPoint doesn't allow "Delete Point" but I am happy to hear that it's fixed in newer versions.

Comment: This is fantastic!  At first I glanced past this answer as I thought it was specific to ovals and circles, but it worked great to remove one side of a box (actually, a box with two rounded corner, to make it look like a rounded square bracket).

Comment: Happy it helped @StevenC.Howell - The original question was asking about circles, so that is why the answer was written with that slant.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

1. Add the circle then a rectangle.

[image]

2. Change the Shape fill and Shape Outline colors f the rectangle to White.

[image]

3. Group both shapes, so they move together if/when you move the circle.

Comment: The white rectangle still exists, which causes problems for my subsequent drawing.